# Why is my google streetview image getting a 403

Tags: google-maps

I am using google map v3 and having a problem downloading images to the browser.  For example, I am getting a 403 on this url from inside my app:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=639x126&location=40.2955607969073,-111.878581528594&fov=120&heading=235&pitch=3`

but if I paste the same url in directly into my browser, I can see the image just fine.

What should I look at to figure this out?  I don't know where to go.

Answer (score 0):

[The posted URL works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ry4yhnvc/) on jsfiddle and StackOverflow.

[The street view API now **requires** a key for **new domains**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/get-api-key) (this is a change as of June 22, 2016, jsfiddle is grandfathered, at least for now).

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=639x126&location=40.2955607969073,-111.878581528594&fov=120&heading=235&pitch=3" />
```

[image]